# Using a jquery ajax call with dotnetnuke

Tags: jquery, ajax, dotnetnuke

Im just trying to do the easiest ajax call such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "module.aspx/testSub",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        alert("Works!");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Error");
    }
});
</script>
```

And here is my codebehind

```
Public Sub testSub()
    lblTest1.Text = "HelloWorld!!!1!"
End Sub
```

But it always returns an error.

Comment: The method should be static. Also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you mean to change my method to public shared sub? And the error im getting is the alert i created myself ^

Comment: jQuery automatically forwards the error text and server response to your error callback - you just have to ready the callback to receive those arguments. See [the jQuery docs on this](http://api.jquery.com/error/). Please edit the question to include the returned error text and serve response.

Comment: im unsure to how to collect the error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

First of all it will help to get a bit more information back on your error object.  The Best way is to update your error function to handle the signature supported by jquery which is `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` the "errorThrown" will have some more information. ([See this API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) Your code MIGHT look like this with it included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "module.aspx/testSub",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        alert("Works!");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error:" + errorThrown);
    }
});
</script>
```

Now, aside from this, I believe you have some issues with the path.  Within DNN your module resides within /DesktopModules/ModuleName/.  Your Custom ASPX page that has your service methods in it resides within there.  (NOTE: If you are NOT using a custom aspx page, and doing your methods inside of your ascx, you will NOT be able to call them directly.)

Most likely your url will need to be something like /DesktopModules/MyModule/module.aspx/testusb or similar.  (Also be sure to mark the method as a ScriptService using the proper attribute.)

Comment: Hi, I have the same code but there is an error throwing '/DesktopModules/MyModule/module.aspx/function' not found 404. Is there any possible solution to that error? I got no clue.. ==

Comment: WHen you get this error it is most likely a path issue.  Try to make the request directly and ensure that your page is there etc

Answer (score 0):

for DNN please try this.

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]